# jqGrid free set defaults for `styleUI`, `iconSet`, `width` and `direction`

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

We are using jqGrid free 4.13.5 ...

Is it possible to set the default `styleUI`, `iconSet`, `width` and `direction` ?!

I tried something like:

```
 $.jgrid.defaults.styleUI = "bootstrap"
 $.jgrid.styleUI = "bootstrap"
```

I have review the http://free-jqgrid.github.io/api-documentation/index.html grid but could not find any answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you use `styleUI` property. One should use `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` or `guiStyle: "bootstrapPrimary"` option to specify the Bootstrap GUI Style (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap)).

One can change any parameter by setting the corresponding property of `$.jgrid.defaults`. Thus you can use

```js
$.jgrid.defaults.guiStyle = "bootstrap";
```

or

```js
$.jgrid.defaults.guiStyle = "bootstrap";
$.jgrid.defaults.iconSet = "fontAwesome";
```

to change default values of the options `guiStyle: "jQueryUI"` and `iconSet: "jQueryUI"` (or `iconSet: "glyph"`) to `guiStyle: "bootstrap", iconSet: "fontAwesome"`.

In the same way you can set default value of any other parameter of jqGrid. For example `$.jgrid.defaults.direction = "rtl";`. By the way the default `direction` will be set from the locale, which you use.

Comment: Dear @Oleg Thanks, Is there any where I can find the list of these options.